# running powershell command from batch fails but works in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Im trying to run:

```
netsh lan show interfaces  | findstr /i "GUID" > test.txt
set /p ethguid=<test.txt
echo %ethguid:~23%> test2.txt
set /p ethguidclean=<test2.txt
echo %ethguidclean%
powershell.exe -Command " Rename-Item "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{%ethguidclean%}" -NewName "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" "
pause
```

but i fails with error:

```
Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '8b384d18-7877-44ea-9b48-5f634a0ff1f6'.
At line:1 char:2
+  Rename-Item HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

and if I run command directly in powershell it works! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your `"`s you're not passing a single command string, but a strange sequence of strings.

Comment: I think you should retrieve the GUID using PowerShell too! netsh.exe is reportedly soon to be removed from future versions of Windows, and is not needed for this task. Example PS command: ```Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { ($_.AdminStatus -Eq 'Up' -And $_.MediaConnectState -Eq 1) -And $_.NdisPhysicalMedium -Eq 14 } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceGuid```. Now as you're already using PowerShell for the registry change, you already have the subkey string you need!

Comment: For example instead of using the retrieved GUID, in the registry string, you could use ```$(Get-NetAdapter | ? { ($_.AdminStatus -Eq 'Up' -And $_.MediaConnectState -Eq 1) -And $_.NdisPhysicalMedium -Eq 14 }).InterfaceGuid``` directly...

Comment: will look into these suggestions thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change inside double quotes to single:

```
powershell.exe -Command " Rename-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{%ethguidclean%}' -NewName '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' "
```